# javascript parses date string with browser timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
var dts = "2019-05-26" // this value came from browser query like "d=1&date=2019-05-26"

var date = new Date(dts)
console.log(JSON.stringify(date))
```

which prints:

```
#=> "2019-05-25T19:00:00.0000Z"
```

## Problem

I get this date from user input. Format only contains year, month and day. Problem happens when user browser's timezone applied on parsing. Sometimes, I get correct date in a day but sometimes i get one day before. This causes wrong database querying.

How can I convert this Date object to UTC? Because **I need it as a Date object not as a string.**

Is there any library that can help me parsing dates at UTC and get back as Date Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Moment UTC](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to normalize the time